# Gnome overview - how to remove applications from certain search keywords?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

Pressing the system (windows) key opens an app search interface I think is called the "overview"

On ubuntu GNOME 16.04, how can I remove applications from certain search keywords in the overview?

E.g.

Typing "sound" brings up audacity, but I'm typing "sounds" to bring up the "Sound" application to change volume and devices.

Typing "display" brings up ImageMagick (which is non-interactive), so I'm typing "displays" to bring up the screen manager.

How can I remove these apps from keywords in overview search?

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit `.desktop` files located in `/usr/share/applications/`

From what I've found search is based on the `Name`, `GenericName` and `Comment` properties inside `.desktop` files, so by changing these properties you should be able to filter which apps are shown.

You can edit `.desktop` files in any text editor.

Comment: `grep magick /usr/share/applications/*.*` and `grep sound` didn't find anything

Comment: Your grep search is case-sensitive add `-i`.

Comment: For me, Gnome also seemed to search the Exec property.

Comment: After some more research seems like it looks at all properties, but these few have the most information about the application.
Oh and you might want to check: [This](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c) and look for the `g_desktop_app_info_search` function.